# How to pass Entity and ID in Generic Repository?

Tags: c#, generics

```
public interface IRepository<TEntity, in TID> where TEntity : IAggregateRoot
{
    TEntity Find(TID id);
}
```

Its implimentation is given below

```
    public class Repository<TEntity, TID> : IRepository<TEntity, TID> where TEntity : class, IAggregateRoot
{
    public virtual TEntity Find(TID id)
    {
        return _unitOfWork.Session.Get<TEntity>(id);
    }
}
```

How to pass **TID** in above repository?

Answer (score 0):

It is a generic type. You have to define it when instance the repository. For sample, for an entity called `Product` where the `Id` is an `int`.

```
var productRepository = new Repository<Product, int>();

// to call a method, you have to pass the TID defined, which is an int 
// and it will return a TEntity, that is a Product.
Product product = productRepository.Find(1);
```